# Retrieve protein sequence from Mgnify given only accession code

Tags: data-download

I only have the accession codes of several proteins from the MGnify database (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/metagenomics/). I would like to retrieve the full amino acid sequence data from the database, but I have not been able to find a way to do this using the web server or available API.

The website provides sequence search with the HMMER tool (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/metagenomics/sequence-search/search/phmmer). However, I need the sequence data to search with HMMER.

How can I get the protein sequence only with the accession code?

P.S: An example of the accession code is MGYP001242958860.